# Design Manager: Content Query (Enterprise Wiki)

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part, design-manager

Using Design Manager, Is it possible to `filter` the Content Query web part using the `Wiki Categories`?  For example, if the current wiki page has a category of `InfoPath`, the `Content Query` web part should list all pages with the same category?

Below is my attempt but I keep getting an error message **Cannot save all of the property settings for this Web Part. One or more errors have occurred. See below for details.**

[image]

Below is the only error I could find:

[image]

**EDIT 09/04/2018**
I found this [post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qlkY.png) where it provided part of the answer.
In SharePoint Designer, after I pasted the HTML code for Content Query, I made the following changes:

- DataMappingViewFields="{`List GUID`}"
- DataMappings="Description:|ImageUrl:{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},PublishingRollupImage,Image;|Title:{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Title,Text;|LinkUrl:{`List GUID`}
- FilterDisplayValue1="[PageFieldValue:`column name`]"
- FilterValue1="[PageFieldValue:`column name`]"

As the post suggested, the original `List GUID` was different from the actual `Pages` library GUID. To bypass the error message from the Design Manager Content Query UI, I just typed any text in the filter value and replaced it with `[PageFieldValue:column name]`.

Answer (score 0):

In my test, the `[PageFieldValue:Wiki Categories]` can be applied and it works as expected.

Type the display name of the site or list column, not the internal name, compare the results.

[image]

Comment: @JoannW_MSFT sorry for the late response. I finally got a chance to test this out and I'm still getting the same error message. Ignoring it and pasting the HTML snippet, my page layout just displays `Content Query` without displaying any links with the same category as the current page.

Comment: It works if I actually type the filter value but I can't get it to work using `[PageFielValue:FieldName]`